# Drupal 7 blog post wont appear

Tags: drupal, blogs

I'm having a problem with the Drupal 7 blog system. If I add new content the blog post doesn't appear. I only see the new post when I click on "admins blog"; then the url will change to `/admin` and I see the new one. I just can't figure it out and I really need help with that.

I tried to look into settings, but I did not find anything that helps me.

Can someone please give me good tips how to resolve this problem. I'm new in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

More information would be helpful. What path are you trying to see it at?
Why do you think it should appear there?
Can you see it if you go to /admin/content?
Is the post have the "published" option checked?
How about the "publish to front page" option?